# yii2: daterange picker get value to change some field

Tags: jquery, yii2, daterangepicker

i have activeform with daterange picker, if i select start date and end date form daterangepicker, the date range value/duration, it will be calculated with some data automatically

```
<div class="pelaksana-form">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'options'=>['id'=>'pelaksanaForm', 'data-pjax'=>true, ]
    ]); ?>

    <label class="control-label">Range Perjalanan Dinas</label>
            <?= DatePicker::widget([
            'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_RANGE,
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'tgl_berangkat',
            'attribute2' => 'tgl_pulang',
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Start date'],
            'options2' => ['placeholder' => 'End date'],

            'form' => $form,
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                'autoclose' => true,
            ]
        ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($mdanggaran, 'uangharian')->textInput(['value' => $sbu->pesawat_pp ])?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

range value (day) will calculated with "uangharian"

i think it use jquery, but i don't know, i don't find any demo source code

Comment: How `$model` related with `$sbu` and `$mdanggaran`? U want to save result of range to `$mdanggaran->uangharian `?

Comment: @DenisOstrovsky yes, that is different model, i want to save to mdanggaran